# Magento - Convert a module using <rewrite> to use Events for the Sales > Order Grid

Tags: events, magento, magento-1.5

I've made a simple module that adds extra fields to the **Sales > Order Grid**. It works great but the problem is that another module we're using `<rewrites>` the order grid to add their field to the grid. I wanted to try to change it to use ***Events*** instead (besides, it's a better method)...

The issue is that I've been trying and trying and I just can't make it happen. (Maybe I just can't grasp the event/observer concept yet...)

Here is my current module structure:

```
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/controllers [empty]
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/Helper [empty]
app/code/local/Artizara/OrderGridAdditions/Model [empty]
```

Inside my **Grid.php** file, I have copied the main Grid.php file contents into my Grid.php file and edited the `_getCollectionClass()`, `_prepareCollection()` and `_prepareColumns()` functions.

I've changed the `_getCollectionClass()` to this:

```
//return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
return 'sales/order_collection';
```

I've changed the `_prepareCollection()` to this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id',array('sfog.shipping_name','sfog.billing_name'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight','sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id','sfo.created_at','sfo.status','sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total','shipping_description','sfo.total_item_count'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"',array('sfoa.street','sfoa.city','sfoa.region','sfoa.postcode','sfoa.telephone'));
//$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfop' => 'sales_flat_order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id = sfop.entity_id',array('sfop.method'));

$this->setCollection($collection);

return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

I've added columns to the `_prepareColumns()` like this (only added one here as example):

```
$this->addColumn('total_item_count', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Items'),
            'index' => 'total_item_count',
            'filter_index' => 'sfo.total_item_count',
            'width' => '50px',
    ));
```

In my `config.xml` file I have a simple `<rewrite>`:

```
<modules>
    <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <ordergridadditions>
            <class>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Block</class>
        </ordergridadditions>
    </blocks>

</global>
```

***Changing it over to Events/Observers***

I've been trying a lot to change this up to a module that uses an **Event** but am hitting a wall with it. I've been trying to follow some other answers on here (the ones that are not rewrites, but they use a different method to add custom tables to the grid from the database). I'm looking to use the **same setup I already have**.

I've added `/Helper/Data.php` container that contains this:

```
class Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{ }
```

In `/etc/config.xml` I've tried many things. Here's my latest attempt:

```
<modules>
    <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
</modules>

<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Observer>
                    <class>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addAdditionsToGrid</method>
                </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Observer>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>

<global>


    <models>
        <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
            <class>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Model</class>
        </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
    </models>

    <blocks>
        <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
            <class>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Block</class>
        </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
    </blocks>

    <helper>
        <Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
            <class>Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Helper</class>
        </Artizara_OrderGridAdditions>
    </helper>


</global>
```

Then in `/Model/Observer.php` I have:

```
class Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Model_Observer {

    public function addAdditionsToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            // code here
        }
}
```

Inside `addAdditionsToGrid()`, I've tried ***many*** different things including copying the entire `Grid.php` file but nothing seems to work (errors) :(

Please help guide me in remaking this simple module using **Events** please!

Answer (score 1):

There is no (good) way to add a column to Sales Order Grid with Observers, because there is no event call. Take a look yourself for `Mage::dispatchEvent` inside `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` and all superclasses.

I think the best practice is extend the grid class like this:

```
class Artizara_OrderGridAdditions_Block_Sales_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        $this->addColumn(/* your definition here */);
    }
}
```

If you really need do this by observers, you can watch the `adminhtml_block_html_before` event and dig a way out, but a lot of blocks will call this event either.

Comment: So you're saying that the only way (or "best way") is just to extend the grid class like I've already done? What about conflicts with other extensions (hence why I'm trying this...)? I guess I'd need help on "digging a way out" since I can't seem to make this work...

Comment: You can simple copy `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` to app/code/local and add the `Mage::dispatchEvent` call where you need, calling your own observers. However, in this way you may have troubles with upgrading Magento in future.

Comment: I want to thank you for your continued help. I know you can use (core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before) as the event to add a massaction option to the dropdown list (on the Sales > Order Grid area). I've tried using this but I still can't seem to get it to work and I think it's because I'm missing something - like file(s)/code - somewhere and not the `Event` itself. I'm looking at an event/observer hooks cheat sheet (http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/)

Comment: As I replied first, there is no specific observers into Magento Admin. I test somethings here and I add a column to Admin Sales Order grid with this: `if ($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) { $observer->getBlock()->addColumn(/* column definition */); }` when observing `adminhtml_block_html_before`. This is not a good way, but can make thing easier. I'll keep looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: I think that is not a good way to use `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` since it's called from frontend too.